# jQuery not working in update panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have written jQuery like below lines of code

```
     var prmvar = window.Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
     prmvar.add_endRequest(function () {
         var j = jQuery.noConflict();
         j(document).ready(function () {
             j('#pagination').jcarousel({

             });
             var count = $("#pagination li").size();
             if (count < 10) {
                 alert(count)
                 j(".jcarousel-prev").css('display', 'none');
                 j(".jcarousel-next").css('display', 'none');
             }
         });
     });
```

It does not work in update panel. Please help me !!!

I added the following configuration in web.config file

```
      <system.web.extensions>
      <scripting>
      <scriptResourceHandler enableCompression="false" enableCaching="true" />
      </scripting>
      </system.web.extensions>
```

It still doesnot work !!!

Comment: Any console errors? what exactly happens?

Comment: Sys is not defined

Comment: The problem is in the Sys.WebForms. This will help you http://weblogs.asp.net/chrisri/demystifying-sys-is-undefined

Comment: put this under system.webServer <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />

Comment: sorry to say that it still does not work

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this code will work or not,but you can try this.

```
j(document).ready(function () {
        var j = jQuery.noConflict();
        j('#pagination').jcarousel({

        });
        var count = $("#pagination li").size();
        if (count < 10) {
            alert(count)
            j(".jcarousel-prev").css('display', 'none');
            j(".jcarousel-next").css('display', 'none');
        }
    });

    var prmvar = window.Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    prmvar.add_endRequest(function () {
        var j = jQuery.noConflict();

            j('#pagination').jcarousel({

            });
            var count = $("#pagination li").size();
            if (count < 10) {
                alert(count)
                j(".jcarousel-prev").css('display', 'none');
                j(".jcarousel-next").css('display', 'none');
            }
    });
```

Comment: Sorry to say that I have already written the above code  j(document).ready(function () { .......}); it still does not work

Comment: it is very strange issue

Comment: it works fine on all the pages except the one page in which it is causing troubles

Comment: Yes , usually this issue happens when there is update panel present on the page.

Comment: Well! is there any solution for it.

Comment: well i usually follow above approach to solve this kind of issue .. here are some links that might helpful for you

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/601683/Working-with-jQuery-within-the-ASP-NET-UpdatePanel